# Retrieve user checkout_sessions using stripeid

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I have an application where I am using stripe subscription extension firebase. At one point I want to retrieve user checkout_sessions (preferably the active ones so i can expire them) using user customerId or stripeId (e.g. cus_xxxxxxxxxx). I am not able to find this solution can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to automatically expire Checkout Sessions, then you can directly set the [`expires_at`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-expires_at) property when creating Checkout Sessions (by default the session will automatically expire after 24 hours).

But if that’s not what you need, here are a couple options to list Checkout Sessions for a specific Customer:

List all Checkout Sessions with [`stripe.checkout.sessions.list`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/list) and [auto-pagination](https://stripe.com/docs/api/pagination/auto). Then filter them on your end by checking the [`customer`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-customer) property. However it might be quite slow to iterate over all Checkout Sessions.

Store the Checkout Session ID <-> Customer relationship in your own database or in the [metadata](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object#customer_object-metadata) field of the Customer using [`stripe.customers.update`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update). This way, you can access the Checkout Session ID for each Customer.